# Clustering and data scaling

Tags: clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, scales

I have a dataset with 5 questions, which are scaled 1-10 and income variable, which is nominal.

- Should I standardise all variables with min/max scaler, or convert income to 1-10 scale?
- What is the general rule for dealing with different scales if I want to use hierarchical or kmeans algo?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think there is more information about your problem. But, in the case of k-means, disregarding the income variable, since the answers follow an order scale, you can run the algorithm normally. There are versions of k-means that use ​​nominal variables as well.

Comment: Thanks, I am just hesitating on which way to go: make all vafiables in scale (0,1) or use all categorical.